# how to set default java plug-in version

Tags: plugins, java

I can set the jre version from the Control Panel -> Java -> Java Runtime Environment Settings.
But I cannot figure out how to change the Java Plug-in Version. I would like to use an earlier  java plug-in version, like 1.5.0_12. How can I do that? Thanks

Here is the output in the Java Console:

`Java Plug-in 1.6.0_19
 Using JRE version 1.5.0_12-b04 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM`

Comment: I assume you're using Windows. Which web browser are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would probably be to uninstall Java JRE 1.6.0_19 and install Java JRE 1.5.0_12

Comment: apparently Java detects the latest version and sets it as default. 
I had to uninstall all the way down to 5.0_12. Thanks.

Comment: Remove and Change are very deferent.

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
su - root
```

2.

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.Framework/Versions
```

3.

```
rm CurrentJDK
```

4.

```
ln -s 1.5.0 CurrentJDK
```