# how to switch to another java version?

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to set default java plug-in version](https://superuser.com/questions/148012/how-to-set-default-java-plug-in-version)

I have Java 1.7.0_06 on windows 7. How can I get it to switch to use 1.6.0.23 without uninstalling the newer version?
I have an applet browser program that needs to use the older but it locks up when when i try to use it.

Comment: You can find an easy way from here : http://bit.ly/TD8aww

Answer (score 1):

For command line stuff:

edit the path and java_home variables.  Under my computer-properties-advanced-environment variables etc etc.

For brower:

You will need to change the helper in the browser config - this will be browser dependant.